# django: quering model with many-to-many fields

Tags: python, django

I have models like this

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now when i do

```
Book.objects.get_or_create(subjects=[2,4] , title='Genetics', subtitle='Theory of Genetics')
```

Here the value of subjects is the list of related subjects id.
This gives me an error saying arguments should be string or number a `TypeError`.

How can I handle this situation with multiple subjects ?

Answer (score 1):

You use the __in operator

```
Book.objects.filter(subjects__in=[2,4])
```

It can also be used with a queryset

```
Book.objects.filter(
     subjects__in=Subject.objects.filter(name__contains="interesting"))
```

If you instead want Book with *both* subjects and not just *any* of them  we can use the Q object

```
Book.objects.filter( Q(subject__in=[2]) & Q(subject__in=[4]) )
```

Note that the *any of* operators doest logically fit in to a get_or_create because there isnt enough information to create so you might have to split it up.

Comment: the first query shows all the books which has subjects having id=2 or subjects having id=4. It does not shows books having both subjects

Comment: @wrufesh you didn't say what you want your code to do.

Comment: Yes it does show entries with both, it does not show exclusively entries with both.